# Amazon Basics Powered USB Hub not Powering Pi 2

Tags: pi-2, power-supply, usb-hub

So I bought an Amazon Basics powered USB 3.0 hub for my pi model 2. It works perfectly fine for powering peripherals and data transfer works just fine when my pi is powered off of a separate power adapter. When I use the hub to power the pi with a USB to micro USB cable, it powers up. However, the moment I plug the male USB type A cable into my pi while being powered from the hub, it shuts down and it won't power up. Is there a solution where I can just power the pi from the hub while having the hub plugged into the pi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hubs that **backpower** cannot be used to do this.

Backpowering is when the hub supplies power to the Pi through the same cable as the data cable. Since the hub is already supplying the Pi with power through the USB ports, it cannot also power the Pi from the micro USB port.