# Amazon Basics USB Hub, disable Backpower?

Tags: usb-power, amazon

I've got the same issue as [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/45196/amazon-basics-powered-usb-hub-not-powering-pi-2) question.

My Raspberry Pi 3 will not power up when powered from a powered port on the same Amazon Basics Hub **AND** plugged into the 'USB In' on the Hub.

The linked answer states that the Hub is trying to backpower the Pi and that functionality is not supported.

I would prefer not to have to buy a different hub, so;
**Is there a way to stop a USB Hub backpowering?**

Something like an USB A to B cable without the power component, or could I open up the Hub and remove a connection to stop it sending power?

The Hub will only ever be used to run my Pi so I don't mind making 'destructive' mods to it.

Thanks

Comment: My recommendation is always to use an official Raspberry Pi power supply., they are designed for powering the Pi. I believe what you are trying to do is not going to work and is a bad idea.

Comment: You probably have an old laptop PSU lying around somewhere; they're great because they have a relative large current capacity (3-4 A, typically) and often have built-in current limiting as well. I always use those and a few cheap switching regulators/DC step-down converters (sometimes with added output capacitors) to power the Pi and all the other stuff that I connect to it. For power hungry USB-units like hard-drives, I sometimes cut the cable, to separate data and power, like you suggested. I don't know the hub schematic but cutting the traces internally is also an option (although invasive)

Comment: This is really a question for [Electrical Engineering](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/) since it has nothing to do with the pi beyond being a duplicate of the other one.

Comment: Thanks jDo, I think that might be the solution. Additionally, you make a fair point goldilocks, am I able to move a question?

Comment: I would suggest gettting a proper power supply. A USB 3 hub is speced to supply only .900 amps - well below the recommended current for the Pi.

Answer (score 0):

You are misinformed as are some of the comments. You CANNOT backpower any Pi since the B+ (I reserve comment on the Zero) because the Foundation included proper protective circuitry. There is no published circuit for Pi after the B+, but the power circuit for later versions is assumed to be similar. Inspection of the B+ circuit clearly shows that backpowering is impossible.)

Neither can you power the Pi3 from a compliant hub because it will not supply sufficient current. (It was possible to run earlier Pi because their power requirements were more modest.)

Comment: Thanks Milliways. I knew I couldn't backpower it, and I'm fine with that. I just want to be able to power it from the USB hub (which I am currently doing) but then also be able to use the hub as, well a hub. Right now it is just an over priced power supply as when I plug the hub into the Pi using the A-B cable, whilst it is being powered from one of the Hubs powered ports, it switches off.

Comment: @TheMagicPirate This has been marked off-topic (which is true). Nonetheless most hubs, even if they can supply sufficient current (in breach of specifications) do not meet the minimum voltage needed by the PI. This can easily be confirmed with a voltmeter. You need a proper power supply.